# Full text search on content of documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql, full-text-search, alfresco

I need to save several files like pdf, docx, xslx etc..

I also need to make full text search on that files, for example, file named test.pdf that contains three lines:
firt test line
two my test line
three test line

Given an input like 'my' i need to extract file test.pdf

Can i do it with mongoDB or other tools (aws, alfresco?) ?

Comment: SOLR or ElasticSearch or OpenSearch plus Apache Tika?

Comment: If you're specifically looking at MongoDB, they have full text searching capabilities in their Atlas Search offering. But the full scope of what you're trying to do is important here - something also needs to read/process the incoming file(s) to extract the text for indexing and subsequent searching. The more file types you support the more difficult/complicated that aspect of this will be. Should be a number of other questions on SO about accomplishing those tasks individually